# Automatic starting VLC with network stream

Tags: vlc, streaming

I am trying to automatically open a network stream (rtsp://username:password@IP address:port/Streaming/Channels/101/ in VLC under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. This stream should start automatically after Ubuntu boots.
The VLC version is 3.0.18 Vetinari .
If I manually start the stream in VLC, I get the intended image from the network camera.
How can I make this start completely automatically when starting Ubuntu.

Comment: You can add the command `vlc rtsp://username:password@IP address:port/Streaming/Channels/101/ ` in a [starup application](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en) or in a [systemd user service](https://askubuntu.com/a/1475900) for example.