# Can’t start IPFS daemon - ipfs.service: Failed with result ‘exit-code’

Tags: server, services, aws, aptdaemon

Even though I'm a noob, I decided to launch a new AWS Ubuntu instance for my IPFS node and encountering errors.

I followed this tutorial - https://medium.com/textileio/tutorial-setting-up-an-ipfs-peer-part-i-de48239d82e0 and I have the ipfs.service below

```
[Unit]
Description=ipfs daemon
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ipfs daemon --enable-gc
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
Environment="IPFS_PATH=/data/ipfs"
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But I keep getting this...

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-57:~$ sudo systemctl status ipfs
● ipfs.service - ipfs daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ipfs.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-08-14 01:25:54 UTC; 3s ago
    Process: 78949 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ipfs daemon --enable-gc (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 78949 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 67ms
```

When I run the command `/usr/local/bin/ipfs daemon --enable-gc` independently, it seems to work fine. But I’m not sure why the service refused to work.

The syslog says this...

```
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 systemd[1]: Started ipfs daemon.
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 ipfs[218510]: Initializing daemon...
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 ipfs[218510]: Kubo version: 0.22.0
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 ipfs[218510]: Repo version: 14
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 ipfs[218510]: System version: amd64/linux
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 ipfs[218510]: Golang version: go1.19.12
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 ipfs[218510]: Error: no IPFS repo found in /data/ipfs.
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 ipfs[218510]: please run: 'ipfs init'
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 14 13:49:10 ip-172-31-35-57 systemd[1]: ipfs.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

But when I ran `ipfs init`, I get this.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-57:~$ ipfs init
generating ED25519 keypair...done
peer identity: 12D3KooWQt2nmHF...
initializing IPFS node at /home/ubuntu/.ipfs
Error: ipfs configuration file already exists!
Reinitializing would overwrite your keys
```

Comment: Isn't there some log entries in the bottom of `systemctl status ipfs` also? Please include this, log entries are often useful.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I just added the log

Comment: @ArturMeinild It worked. Thank you. But no idea why when I use $HOME, the path changed to /root. I'm logged in as ubuntu as user.

Comment: Maybe because `systemd`executes its service as root. Also, I've added my comment as answer.

Comment: If you want `$HOME` to expand to your logged-in user instead of the `root`'s home directory, then use a [user service](https://askubuntu.com/a/1475900)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a discrepancy between where `ifps` is initialized, and where the `systemd` unit the configuration to exist.

To make the configuration line up, do one of two things:

1. Run `ipfs init` inside `/data/ipfs` 
   *(to make the data dir `/data/ipfs`)*.
2. Set `Environment="IPFS_PATH=/home/ubuntu"` in the `ipfs.service` file 
   *(to make the data dir `/home/ubuntu`)*