# Create a tmux session at startup before login as user (not root)

Tags: server, startup, tmux

I'm hosting a small minecraft server for my friends on my home, and to make things easier for me, I wanted to make it so when i turn on the pc that is used as server, automatically starts the minecraft server. The thing is that I use tmux to be able to manage the server in case I need to. For that, I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SESSION="server"
SESSIONEXISTS=$(tmux list-sessions | grep -w "$SESSION")

if [ "$SESSIONEXISTS" = "" ]
then

  tmux new-session -d -s "$SESSION" -d -x "$(tput cols)" -y "$(tput lines)"

  tmux rename-window -t 0 'mc'
  tmux send-keys -t 'mc' 'cd magma-1.18.2-40.2.10 && ./run.sh && sudo shutdown now' C-m
  tmux splitw -v

  tmux send-keys -t 'mc' 'glances' C-m
  tmux select-pane -t 0
  tmux splitw -h

  tmux send-keys -t 'mc' 'ngrok start --all' C-m

  tmux select-pane -t 0

fi

tmux attach-session -t "$SESSION":0
```

I've tried to use cron with no success:

```
@reboot bash /home/fpp/startup.sh
```

It just wont start the tmux session.

I also tried with a systemd unit:
[Unit]

```
Description=mcnrelated.service

After=default.target

[Service]

ExecStart=bash /home/fpp/startup.sh

[Install]

WantedBy=default.target
```

but when starting up, I was able to see the service wasn't started because an error.

As a last option I tried to use rc.local:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su -c "./home/fpp/startup.sh" -s /bin/sh fpp
exit 0
```

but again, no tmux session was started.

Can this issue be related to tmux? or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: The way to go is with systemd.

After chatting a lot with ChatGPT, I was able to figure out that on my script, I was using `tput` to get the terminal rows and columns. The issue with that is that it wont return a value when its run as a service, because its not run in a terminal, and it made the script fail. Because of that, I switched to the .tmux.conf file, so i can just call `tmux -t .tmux.conf` and that way I avoid using `tput`.

Also, as ChatGPT recommended, I'm now using a user-level systemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch Minecraft Server and Related Services
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -u -f /home/fpp/tmux-config/tmux.conf
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

the issue now is that tmux is complaining about having no terminal to open:

```
fpp@fpp-server:~$ systemctl --user status mcnrelated.service
× mcnrelated.service - Launch Minecraft Server and Related Services
     Loaded: loaded (/home/fpp/.config/systemd/user/mcnrelated.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-09-21 11:42:09 -03; 8min ago
    Process: 1319 ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -u -f /home/fpp/.tmux.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1319 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 37ms

sep 21 11:42:09 fpp-server systemd[550]: Starting mcnrelated.service - Launch Minecraft Server and Related Services...
sep 21 11:42:09 fpp-server tmux[1319]: open terminal failed: not a terminal
sep 21 11:42:09 fpp-server systemd[550]: mcnrelated.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
sep 21 11:42:09 fpp-server systemd[550]: mcnrelated.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sep 21 11:42:09 fpp-server systemd[550]: Failed to start mcnrelated.service - Launch Minecraft Server and Related Services.
```

and that's where I'm now. I've tried using `-u` but that had no success.

The issue is something with tmux, at least for now. Once i can successfully start the service i will try to see if its auto started at boot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I launch a script in a terminal window from a service](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475822/how-can-i-launch-a-script-in-a-terminal-window-from-a-service)

Comment: "*before login as user*", "*(not root)*" and "*`After=default.target`*" probably will contradict with each other ... Which one do you want?

Comment: @Raffa I want the script to be executed as user, as soon as the system has completed the boot process. I don't really know what I'm doing honestly, i just followed [this](https://linuxhint.com/run-shell-script-startup/) guide and i had no luck on what i want to do

Comment: When using a system service, you’ll need to specify the full real path to interpreter e.g. `/bin/bash` and then your script will run as root by default unless you explicitly specify a user and your user's crontab won’t work before login that way as you seem to use commands in your script that require a user graphical session running AFAIK and even after login a user service is preferred to crontab for such script or you might be able to run your script as a startup application after login

Comment: @Raffa thanks for the suggestions. I think i'm getting closer and closer. It seems that when using systyemd (as root or as user) it was complaining about an "incorrect size". That had to do with ```tput``` command, that isnt supposed to work on a non-tty environment. So i changed routes and decided to make a ```.tmux.conf``` file so i dont rely on ```tput```. The issue now is that tmux is complaining about not having a terminal available, and i cant seem to find a solution. I updated the question so there is more context

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by following [this](https://superuser.com/a/1582196/1692032) solution.