# Run a command using system.service ./start start

Tags: networking, server, scripts, systemd, services

I'm trying to get my system.service file to run a command that is inside my `start` script. I've tried adding `StandardInput=` which did not work, so I believe I misunderstood how that operates. I've also tried the following unit below:

This fails, of course. How would I execute the command `./start start` ?

```
Description=Service File
Wants=network-online.target
After=syslog.target network.target nss-lookup.target network-online.target

[Service]
User=host
WorkingDirectory=/home/host/Server/
ExecStart=/home/host/Server/start start
Restart=always
RestartSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: the file name is `start.sh` and it executes three functions, Start, Stop, Compile. I want it to do `start`.

Comment: I type the command ./start start and is seems to process everything normally. I tried ./start.sh start and it failed to start.
For now I managed to create three different scripts to run it on start up, but if I could get it in one that'd be super helpful.

Comment: In the root directory for my server, where all the start files are compiled, I can run my command `./start start` I can get everything green lit. If I try to run the command ./start.sh start it will throw the following error:
`/home/host/Server$ ./start.sh start`
`bash: ./start.sh: No such file or directory`
It runs scripts inside that start file to initialise the servers activating and connecting the 3 ports of the game. I got each of these 3 services on their own individual files to be enabled at startup.

Comment: I guess when you say "root directory for my server", you mean `/home/host/Server`, not the actual root directory `/`. So you have an executable file `/home/host/Server/start`, ie. an executable file named `start` which lies in the directory `/home/host/Server` of your server. But you also have a file named `start.sh`? In which directory does that lie? Is it executable too? What is the difference between the two? Please be a bit more forthcoming with information about your environment. Bear in mind that I cannot see what's on your server.

Comment: Yes the "root" of the directory being the `Server` folder. I've attached an image in the link below to show the file. It seems to be a standard script and executes as it should, for the last 10+ years. 
https://i.imgur.com/z4VVJm9.png

What I need it to do is execute a command, or function, "start"  when the system.service file is enabled. 
`ExecStart=/home/host/Server/start start` 
This does not work. Is there a way to run a function like this in a system.service file?

Comment: Ok, so we've sorted out that your script file is called `start`, not `start.sh`. You may want to edit your question to fix that. As to running it from a systemd unit, your approach is basically correct and should work. So it remains to diagnose why it doesn't work in your case. I cannot say anything specific without knowing what's actually inside your `start` file, but generally speaking you would inspect relevant log files to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: What does your script actually do? Does it require a graphical desktop session? Does id launch some graphical window? Can you show us the code of your script? How do you know/identify that it doesn't work from the systemd unit? Do you get any errors? What's the output of `systemctl status name.service`  where `name.service` is your unit's file name?

Comment: ... Also, please see if [How can I launch a script in a terminal window from a service](https://askubuntu.com/q/1475822) helps.

Comment: Thanks. A py script can work to solve what I need. That's a good work around! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your systemd service as follows:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/home/host/Server/start.sh start'
```

Then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```