How to automatically mount a hard drive at runtime in Ubuntu 22.04 server
I found many solutions online, but each had specific errors or downsides, that made them unconvenient.
I want: On an Ubuntu 22.04 server, connect hard drive at runtime, not only boot, via sata and automatically mount them at a predefined directory per hard drive. It is ok, if the directory is just empty if the drive is not connected. But the directory must be reachable even when empty.
I tried: udev calling a simple mount script, udev calling systemctl and starting a mount unit with it, udev and using systemd-mount, systemds automount unit files.
The udev attempts failed all. The mount script just returns exit code 32. Would have wondered, if that worked. Using systemds automount unit files works in automounting the drives. But as soon as the drive is disconnected, trying to reach the now empty directory leads to massive lags as automounting attempts are made, which time out due to the requested device not starting.
Calling systemd units from udev are also timing out due to the required device not available for unknown reasons. Additionally it is a pain to have directories with white spaces in the name when using udev and systemd, as the unit file needs to have the path in its name.
My systemd unit files:
[Unit]
Description=Hotswap External Game Backups
After=blockdev@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-6ac875cb\x2d2a99\x2d494a\x2db7d9\x2d60619646155d.target

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/6ac875cb-2a99-494a-b7d9-60619646155d
Where=/media/archive/public/GameBackups
Type=ext4
Options=rw,dev,exec,noauto,nouser,sync,relatime,nofail

[Unit]
Description=Automount for external Game Backups

[Automount]
Where=/media/archive/public/GameBackups

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

My udev rule:
# rule for automounting hard drives
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}="6ac875cb-2a99-494a-b7d9-60619646155d", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger --tag 'udev automount' 'Trying to MOUNT external game backups.'", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl start media-archive-public-GameBackups.mount"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}="6ac875cb-2a99-494a-b7d9-60619646155d", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger --tag 'udev automount' 'Trying to UNMOUNT external game backups.'", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl stop media-archive-public-GameBackups.mount"

As i said, udev times out because the After target of the unit file is not reached. I can manually start the systemd mount unit and it works flawlessly.
I use hotswap bays, which are just connected to sata and put hard drives in it.
Any help appreciated!

Have you tried? ,,,  open the "Disks" app (comes standard).  Choose your disk from the menu.  Click the gears icon. Choose mount at startup. reboot.

You do not mount a drive, but mount formatted partitions. And you use fstab. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab Disks typically does not have best parameters, but depends on format of partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/164926/how-to-make-partitions-mount-at-startup & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029040/how-to-manually-mount-a-partition & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting/1013700#1013700 Good examples:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab

It is a server and i specifically wrote, not only at boot! So i want to just push a drive in and it gets mounted at a predefined directory.
And yes, i know, one mounts partitions. Sorry for my bad wording. It is kinda shown in my files, i use uuids there, which are created for mountable partitions, if i remember correctly.

Re UDEV calling a script see https://askubuntu.com/q/1417539 and for UDEV tagging a systemd unit see example https://askubuntu.com/a/1503861

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions & ither systemd-automount or autofs can be used.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2495341 &
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#Automount_with_systemd & For USB connected stuff, use autofs, always. use /misc/ typically
use noauto if mount issues

@oldfred systemd-automount hangs the system if the device is not present but automount is requested, as i wrote in my question. Autofs looks promising, but i found another method, that i will put in my answer to my question.

@Raffa The script solution looks really good. Its a background running script, that listens for an udev event.

In the comments, many solutions were presented. They can be found in questions with very specific titles. That made it difficult for me to find them. So i present my solution here.
This worked for me:

Have a udev rule starting a systemd service
Have that oneshot systemd service stating a script
Have that script calling the mount command

As far as i understood, udev only releases the devices for the system after handling all rules. This is the reason, that directly called actions on the device symlinks do not work.
Script:
#!/bin/bash

ACTION=$1
if [[ ${ACTION} == "mount" ]]; then
  /bin/mount -o rw,dev,exec,auto,nouser,sync,relatime,nofail /dev/disk/by-uuid/6ac875cb-2a99-494a-b7d9-60619646155d "/media/archive/public/Game Backups"
else
  /bin/umount "/media/archive/public/Game Backups"
fi
/usr/bin/logger -t 'game backups mount script' "${ACTION} on /media/archive/public/Game Backups"

Oneshot systemd service:
[Unit]
Description=Mount External Game Backups

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mount-external-game-backups.sh mount
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/mount-external-game-backups.sh umount

udev rule:
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="6ac875cb-2a99-494a-b7d9-60619646155d", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger -t 'udev mount game backups' 'starting mount script for game backups'", RUN+="/bin/systemctl start mountgamebackups.service"
ACTION=="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="6ac875cb-2a99-494a-b7d9-60619646155d", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger -t 'udev mount game backups' 'stopping mount script for game backups'", RUN+="/bin/systemctl stop mountgamebackups.service"

