Why the key After performing automount?
I want to make an automatic backup to a flash drive after auto-mounting it.
To do this, I wrote in /etc/fstab...
UUID=0698-A3CF  /flash  vfat  noauto,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=15,x-systemd.device-timeout=15

And in /etc/systemd/system/ I created the my_backup.service unit. I filled it out according to these instructions.
[Unit]
Description=My backup script trigger
Requires=flash.automount
After=flash.automount

[Service]
ExecStart=/myfolder/python_backup.py

[Install]

WantedBy=flash.automount

The Python script works great if I run it separately and almost perfectly if I run it by mounting a flash drive. Almost, except... actually copying the necessary files. The log says “No such device /flash/newfolder100500”. In addition, by commenting out the functions for working with files, using a delay in the Python script and the ls /flash command, I found out that the flash drive is not mounted until the script is completed to the end. But the unit says “After”! Is it possible to rewrite the unit so that the Python script starts executing after mounting the flash drive?

Going by https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.automount.html, an automount unit being up only means that the mount will be done when some file in the mount path is accessed. You should be depending on the mount unit instead, or rather use RequiresMountsFor and avoid using direct dependencies on mounts/automounts.

This https://askubuntu.com/a/1503861 and this https://askubuntu.com/a/1417803 can work for your purpose and save your time although not direct answers to your question.

@muru I change .automount to .mount but there is a problem. As you said, automount make mount every time when something needs my usb flash drive. Thus, inserting a flash drive does not lead to a correct backup. And the subsequent command ls /flash, which causes the unit to restart, leads. I add a ExexSartPre=ls /flash to the unit but this did not lead to success. Is it possible to run my script exactly by inserting a USB flash drive?

Assuming it gets mounted on insert, your unit could be RequiredBy and After the mount unit for the drive

@muru Can you please write an answer with a whole unit?
And explain why my initial settings in the unit from the original post do not work, but the settings you provided will work?
